# Como encadear funções async no typescript?

Tags: angular, funções, typescript, async

> Tenho duas funções assíncronas A e B.
>
> Como faço para inicializar a função B apenas depois que a função A esteja completa?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  data: Data[] = [];

  calendarOptions: Options;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    const var1 = await this.A();
    const var2 = await this.B();
  }


  async A(){
      this.dataService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
        items.forEach(item => {
          this.data.push(item);
        })
      });

  }

  async B(){
      this.calendarOptions = {
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-11-23',
        navLinks: true,
        events: [{
            id:1,
            title:this.data[0].title,
            start:"2017-11-23 09:00:00",
            end:"2017-11-23 11:00:00",
            color:"#0071c5"
        }]
      };

  }
}
```

Comment: async / await foram feitos para ser usados em [conjunto com Promises](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html), coisa que seu código não faz. Não seria melhor simplesmente chamar o método B dentro do `onNext` do `subscribe`?

Comment: Cara você poderia me dar um exemplo de como isso funciona?
Eu procuro tutoriais e não encontro nada que me esclareça.

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que está seu `async` e `awayt` não fazem nada e acho que estão até errados. Também não tem o porque de salvar o retorno das funções já que as mesmas não retornam nada

Você pode passar um callback para ser executado pela função `A` depois de finalizar sua operação assíncrona:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.A(this.B);
}
A(callback){
  this.dataService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
    this.data = this.data.concat(items);
    callback();
  });
}
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isso que você me falou mas continua retornando erro.
'cannot read property 'data' of undefined'. Como se data não estivesse sendo carregado e eu testei o carregamento com console. É como se B estivesse carregando antes de A.

Comment: Então seu problema é outro e não possui relação com `async await`, não é necessário esse loop, pode concatenar usando `this.data = this.data.concat(items)`, isso irá concatenar os arrays

Comment: Cara foi mal mas continua sem funcionar. Mesmo erro.

Comment: Tem certeza que está escrevendo o `this` corretamente? Porque esse erro está dizendo que está tentando acessar a propriedade `data` em uma variável com valor `undefined`, ou seja, o `this` não tem como ser `undefined`, deve ter algum erro de ortografia ou este erro é em alguma outra linha que não estou vendo

Comment: Tenho cara tenho. Eu fiz questão de copiar igualzinho o que você postou aqui. Mas você foi tão gente fina que eu compartilhar o código com você.https://github.com/Rosnaldo/Calendar